# Spark -Scala Nested array DF - How to update value based on condition without changing structure?

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, struct

### I have a structure like the following in orc/parquet format.

```
{
  "Register": {
    "Persons": [
      {
        "Name": "Name1",
        "Age": 12,
        "Address": [
          {
            "Apt": "Apt1"
          }
        ],
        "Phone": [
          {
            "PhoneNum": 1234
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Name2",
        "Age": 14,
        "Address": [
          {
            "Apt": "Apt2"
          }
        ],
        "Phone": [
          {
            "PhoneNum": 55555
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

---

I need to create a new DF based on condition Apt= Apt1 and Change Phone number of that entry to 7777.
NB: Need to keep the same structure.
I have tried out couple methods in scala-spark, but not able to update the nested array struct type. Any expert advise will be helpful.

Update: Following this link, i am able to get the named_struct variables. When it comes to array, I am not able to get the answer.
https://kb.databricks.com/data/update-nested-column.html#how-to-update-nested-columns

Comment: Would each top-level-entry of your dataframe be the "Register" or a "Person"? Could you please post the output of `df.printSchema()`?

Comment: |-- Register: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Persons: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Address: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Apt: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Phone: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- PhoneNum: long (nullable = true)

Comment: @werner This is sample thing, I have given the Schema .      I tried recreate a DF as similar to the following from existing DF, but not able to replace the existing values in Nested Array.           
selectExp

named_struct(Register,named_struct{Persons,array(named_struct{"Name", Register.Persons.Name,

"Phone",Register.Persons.Phone})). as named_struct """).select($"named_struct.Register")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use [case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) to convert the nested structure into a set of simple Scala classes that can be more easily handled - or in Spark terms: use a (typed) [Dataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) instead of a untyped DataFrame.

```
case class Phone(var PhoneNum:String)
case class Apt(Apt:String)
case class Person(Name: String, Age: Long, Address:Array[Apt], Phone:Array[Phone])
case class Register(Persons:Array[Person])
case class TopLevel(Register:Register)
```

Convert the dataframe into a dataset and then apply a `map` call on each entry of the dataset:

```
val df = ...
val ds = df.as[TopLevel]
val transformed = ds.map(tl => {
  for( p <- tl.Register.Persons) {
    if(p.Address.contains(Apt("Apt1"))) p.Phone.transform(_ => Phone("7777"))
  }
  tl
})
transformed.toJSON.show(false)
```

prints:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"Register":{"Persons":[{"Name":"Name1","Age":12,"Address":[{"Apt":"Apt1"}],"Phone":[{"PhoneNum":"7777"}]},{"Name":"Name2","Age":14,"Address":[{"Apt":"Apt2"}],"Phone":[{"PhoneNum":"55555"}]}]}}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

*A remark on the data structure/schema in the question*:

As the question is asked, a dataframe of registers is used. That means that each entry of the dataframe contains a single register. It would be more intuitively if the dataframe contained a list of persons and if this list of persons was called "Register". This would lead to a much easier structure of the data. In this case, the classes `TopLevel` and `Register` could be omitted.

Comment: Thanks.  The second part, as you mentioned it may not be first element of the array.

Comment: What exactly would be the expected behaviour if one person had more than one address and/or more than one phone number?

Comment: Thanks a lot Werner . Logic works well. But I have a problem like , I can't have a fixed schema in case class, that will be changing in actual scenario.

Comment: You might want to rewrite your question or ask a new one that describes more in detail what is fixed and what the conditions are when the data should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is the mapping of your json in dataframe,
Then we create a custom UDF that takes in input the Apt column, the PhoneNum column and the new phone number allows to change the phone number if Apt = Apt1

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val inputJson = "{\"Register\":{\"Persons\":[{\"Name\":\"Name1\",\"Age\":12,\"Address\":[{\"Apt\":\"Apt1\"}],\"Phone\":[{\"PhoneNum\":1234}]},{\"Name\":\"Name2\",\"Age\":14,\"Address\":[{\"Apt\":\"Apt2\"}],\"Phone\":[{\"PhoneNum\":55555}]}]}}"


    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val outputDataFrame = sparkSession.read.option("multiline", true).option("mode","PERMISSIVE")
      .json(Seq(inputJson).toDS)
      .select(
          // First layer mapping
          col("Register").getItem("Persons").as("Persons")
        )
      .withColumn("Persons", explode(col("Persons")))
        .select(
          // Second layer mapping
          col("Persons").getItem("Name").as("Name"),
          col("Persons").getItem("Age").as("Age"),
          col("Persons").getItem("Address").as("Address"),
          col("Persons").getItem("Phone").as("Phone")
        )
        .select(col("Name"),col("Age"),
          // last layer mapping
          col("Address").getItem("Apt").as("Apt"),
          col("Phone").getItem("PhoneNum").as("PhoneNum"))
        .withColumn("Apt", explode(col("Apt")))
        .withColumn("PhoneNum", explode(col("PhoneNum")))
        .withColumn("PhoneNum", changePhoneNumUDF(col("Apt"), col("PhoneNum"), lit(987654))) // apply user defined function to change PhoneNume according to Apt

    outputDataFrame.show


  }
  def changePhoneNum(Apt : String, oldPhoneNum : Long ,NewPhoneNum : Long) : Long = Apt match {
    case "Apt1" => NewPhoneNum
    case _ => oldPhoneNum
  }
  val changePhoneNumUDF = udf(changePhoneNum _)
}
```

Output :

```
+-----+---+----+--------+
| Name|Age| Apt|PhoneNum|
+-----+---+----+--------+
|Name1| 12|Apt1|  987654|
|Name2| 14|Apt2|   55555|
+-----+---+----+--------+
```

Comment: SRV, did it help you ?

Comment: Thanks Simba for the input; for me explode doesn't fit, I need to keep the same JSON kind nested structure